# Modifying an XML file with Dart

Tags: xml, flutter, dart

I want to modify the values in an XML file in a Flutter app.

The XML looks something like this:

```
<Alarm>
    <Type>ReallyLoudAlarm</Type>
    <Issue>2</Issue>
    <Revision>5</Revision>
    <Settings>
        <AlarmVolume type="int" min="0" max="100" unit="%">80</AlarmVolume>
        <AlarmEnabled type="bool"> 1 </AlarmEnabled>
        <AlarmMessage type="str" maxLen="20">Wake up</AlarmMessage>
    </Settings>
</Alarm>
```

Which I am parsing with [this XML parser](https://pub.dev/packages/xml) and reading the values into my UI.

I would just like to update the value of an element by doing something like `document.findAllElements('AlarmVolume').first.text = number.toString();`.

Am I just missing the way to do this, or do I have to rebuild the entire XML file when I save my form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The XML input you posted is invalid, you will get a parse error because `<Settings>` and `<Alarm>` have no (matching) closing tag.
2. `XmlElement.text` is a readonly property, but `XmlElement.innerText` can be used to replace the text contents.
3. To transform the document back to a string (and write it to a file) use `document.toXmlString()`.

Comment: Thanks, .innerText was exactly what I was after, and thanks for spotting the mistakes in my XML, think I missed a line when copying it over!

Comment: I do no find this "XmlElement.innerText" method, im using xml: ^3.4.1, Please let me know which version you using. Thank you.

Comment: You are using a very old version of the package (from 2019), `XmlElement.innerText` is only present since [4.2.0](https://pub.dev/packages/xml/changelog#420). The current version is [5.3.0](https://pub.dev/packages/xml).